# Under IIS 8.0, appcmd or inetmgr cannot make changes to web.config if <runtime>/<assemblyBinding> element is present in the file

Tags: iis-8

In preparing to move some applications to IIS 8, I am getting hresult:c00cef03 error on Windows 10 and Windows Server 2012 R2 when using appcmd.exe or inetmgr to make changes to web.config as long as the web.config file contains runtime/assemblyBinding element.

Has anyone seen this before and what is the workaround?

Below is an example of appcmd output:

```
C:>C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site/Configuration" -section:anonymousAuthentication /username
:""
Applied configuration changes to section "system.webServer/security/authenticati
on/anonymousAuthentication" for "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site/Config
uration" at configuration commit path "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site/
Configuration"
ERROR ( hresult:c00cef03, message:Failed to commit configuration changes.
 )
```

The following is the content of a web.config file that you may use to reproduce the issue. It seems that just the presence of  element would make the error happen, the identity of the assembly does not matter.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <authentication>
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" userName="IUSR" />
      </authentication>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <asm:assemblyBinding xmlns:asm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <asm:dependentAssembly>
        <asm:assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <asm:bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.5.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
      </asm:dependentAssembly>
    </asm:assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Windows 10 runs IIS 10.

Comment: I can reproduce this, but do not find an easy fix. Even IIS Manager cannot make changes in this case, so it should be an MWA bug.

Comment: I think the cause is that `<runtime>` tag and its children have no responding schema information registered in IIS. Whether this might be fixed by adding a schema file is still unknown.

Comment: I do not find <runtime> tag in 2012R2 schema, nor can I in 2008R2 schema; but 2008R2 has no such issue. The cause is probably something else.

Answer (score 1):

**This is not a real answer.**

I don't have access to Microsoft source code, but maintain [an IIS Manager clone](https://jexusmanager.com). So after reading your description I went on and investigated. My conclusion so far is that `<runtime>` tag cannot be easily processed via schema files. (That's why there is no existing schema files to handle it, different from `<system.web>` items, which have their own schema files).

The solution I gave to Jexus Manager is [a new commit](https://github.com/jexuswebserver/JexusManager/commit/3a15b9b7d449aee1fd84a9b734de8028ec5e74e9), where by reading `machine.config` the `<runtime>` tag is being ignored.

I can only guess that IIS Manager in IIS 7.0 and 7.5 also uses the same trick to ignore `<runtime>` tag. But the developer might have hard coded `System.Configuration.IgnoreSection` for .NET Framework 2.0, which won't work for .NET Framework 4.0 and above, and can possibly lead to the you met. One supporting fact is that for IIS 8.0 and above, IIS Manager (and MWA API) runs fully on .NET Framework 4.0, not 2.0 any more.

**Well, at this stage you can only report this bug to Microsoft and hope they can fix it.** And if they don't want to fix, you almost have no choice but use  workarounds, like

- Removing the `<runtime>` tag before calling IIS API, and adding it back when finished).

Unfortunately I don't have enough time to develop a appcmd clone based on Jexus Manager code base. Otherwise, that can be an option for you to try.

Comment: Thanks Lex! I'll open a support ticket with Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft suggestion is to remove the XML namespace prefix from assembly binding elements, which I have verified to have solved the problem. Although it is less than ideal for correct XML syntax to be rejected, this is an acceptable solution.

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.5.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```